# How to remotely update AMI id in Jenkins EC2 plugin?

Tags: jenkins, packer

I have been looking for a way to update AMI id in Jenkins EC2 plugin configuration after a packer build is run. After some digging, I found a promising way to do it **IF** the packer run is done by Jenkins itself, via [postbuild groovy plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ec2-plugin/pull/154) (mind you, this remains to be tested, but looks good)

However I would like to be able to run the packer build anywhere, and have the resulting AMI id updated at Jenkins remotely, presumably via authenticated REST? Is that possible? Where would I start looking?

Comment: Not using it but I'd tackle the problem with a periodic job on Jenkins itself getting the ami id from aws ec2 describe-images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PR you are linking to contains a link to a [python script](https://gist.github.com/marvinpinto/a6c9b5119d418a65d489) that does exactly this, since you can run that script from anywhere you can access your Jenkins server.

Answer (score 3):

Updated the [python script](https://github.com/burukuru/jenkins-update-ec2-ami) from the PR above with:

- CSRF support to work better with Jenkins 2.x
- full support for private Jenkins jobs

Also I wrote up some usage instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best place to start is to have at the end of your packer.json a call to the [manifest](https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/manifest.html) post-processor.

This will contain the full details of the AMI that you have created in JSON format.

eg  "artifact_id": "us-west-1:ami-XXXXXXXX",

This can then be read and acted on by any tooling of your choice.

Source: https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/manifest.html